# Python AttributeError

Tags: python, attributes

I have the following code and cant seem to realized why I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\finalprojectfile-WIP.py", line 292, in <module>
    deck = deck()
  File "C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\finalprojectfile-WIP.py", line 149, in __init__
    del self.deck

AttributeError: deck instance has no attribute 'deck'
```

Here's the code:

```
import simpleguitk as simplegui
import random

# load cards - 949x392 - 
CARD_SIZE = (73, 98)
CARD_CENTER = (36.5, 49)
card_images = simplegui.load_image("http://www.jfitz.com/cards/classic-playing-cards.png")


# initialize some useful global variables
flag1 = False
flag2 = False
win = 0
loss = 0
wind = 0
lossd = 0
count = 0

# define globals for cards
SUITS = ('C', 'S', 'H', 'D')
RANKS = ('A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K')
VALUES = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10}

# define card class
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        if (suit in SUITS) and (rank in RANKS):
            self.suit = suit
            self.rank = rank
        else:
            self.suit = None
            self.rank = None
            print "Invalid card: ", suit, rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.suit + self.rank

    def get_suit(self):
        return self.suit

    def get_rank(self):
        return self.rank

    def draw(self, canvas, pos):
        card_loc = (CARD_CENTER[0] + CARD_SIZE[0] * RANKS.index(self.rank), 
                    CARD_CENTER[1] + CARD_SIZE[1] * SUITS.index(self.suit))
        canvas.draw_image(card_images, card_loc, CARD_SIZE, [pos[0] + CARD_CENTER[0], pos[1] + CARD_CENTER[1]], CARD_SIZE)

# define hand class
class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []
        self.rank1 = []
        self.suit1 = []
        self.position = []
        self.hundred = 0
        self.count = -1

    def __str__(self):
        s = ""
        i = 0
        while i in range(0, len(self.hand)):
            s += (str(self.hand[i]) + " ")
            i += 1
        return s

    def add_card(self, card):
        self.hundred += 100
        self.position.append(self.hundred)
        self.rank1.append(card.get_rank())
        self.suit1.append(card.get_suit())
        self.hand.append(card.get_suit() + card.get_rank())

    # count aces as 1, if the hand has an ace, then add 10 to hand value if it doesn't bust
    def get_value(self):
        self.value = 0
        for i in range(0, len(self.rank1)):
            if (self.rank1[i] == 'A' and self.value <= 10):
                self.value += 11
            else:
                self.value += VALUES.get(self.rank1[i])
        return self.value

    def draw(self, canvas, p, r, s):
        card_location = (CARD_CENTER[0] + CARD_SIZE[0] * RANKS.index(r), 
                    CARD_CENTER[1] + CARD_SIZE[1] * SUITS.index(s))
        canvas.draw_image(card_images, card_location, CARD_SIZE, [p[0] + CARD_CENTER[0], p[1] + CARD_CENTER[1]], CARD_SIZE)  

    def drawback(self, canvas, p):
        card_location1 = (CARD_BACK_CENTER[0], CARD_BACK_CENTER[1])
        canvas.draw_image(card_back, card_location1, CARD_BACK_SIZE, [p[0] + CARD_BACK_CENTER[0], p[1] + CARD_BACK_CENTER[1]], CARD_BACK_SIZE)

# define deck class
class deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.choice = -1
        del self.deck
        self.deck = []
        for i in range(1, 14):
            j = str(i)
            if (j == '1'):
                self.deck.append(Card('C', 'A').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'A').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('S', 'A').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'A').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('H', 'A').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'A').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('D', 'A').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'A').get_rank())
            elif (j == '10'):
                self.deck.append(Card('C', 'T').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'T').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('S', 'T').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'T').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('H', 'T').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'T').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('D', 'T').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'T').get_rank())
            elif (j == '11'):
                self.deck.append(Card('C', 'J').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'J').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('S', 'J').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'J').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('H', 'J').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'J').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('D', 'J').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'J').get_rank())
            elif (j == '12'):
                self.deck.append(Card('C', 'Q').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'Q').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('S', 'Q').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'Q').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('H', 'Q').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'Q').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('D', 'Q').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'Q').get_rank())
            elif (j == '13'):
                self.deck.append(Card('C', 'K').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'K').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('S', 'K').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'K').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('H', 'K').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'K').get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('D', 'K').get_suit() + " " + Card('C', 'K').get_rank())
            else:
                self.deck.append(Card('C', j).get_suit() + " " + Card('C', j).get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('S', j).get_suit() + " " + Card('C', j).get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('H', j).get_suit() + " " + Card('C', j).get_rank())
                self.deck.append(Card('D', j).get_suit() + " " + Card('C', j).get_rank())
    # add cards back to deck and shuffle
    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal_card(self):
        self.choice += 1
        return self.deck[self.choice]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.deck)

#define event handlers for buttons
def deal():
    global flag1, flag2, deck, player, dealer, count, loss, wind
    if (flag1 == True and player.get_value() <= 21):
        loss += 1
        wind += 1
    count = 0
    flag1 = False
    flag2 = False
    player = Hand()
    dealer = Hand()
    deck = deck()
    deck.shuffle()
    for i in range(0, 2):
        deal1 = deck.deal_card()
        split1 = deal1.split()
        card1 = Card(split1[0], split1[1])
        player.add_card(card1)
        deal2 = deck.deal_card()
        split2 = deal2.split()
        card2 = Card(split2[0], split2[1])
        dealer.add_card(card2)

def hit():
    global flag1, flag2, loss, deck, player, dealer, wind, count
    if (count < 5):
        if (player.get_value() < 21) and flag2 == False:
            count += 1
            hit = deck.deal_card()
            split = hit.split()
            card = Card(split[0], split[1])
            player.add_card(card)
            flag1 = True
        if (player.get_value() > 21):
            count = 6
            loss += 1
            wind += 1

def stand():
    global flag1, flag2, win, loss, wind, lossd
    if (flag2 == False and player.get_value() <= 21):
        while (dealer.get_value() < 17):
            hit = deck.deal_card()
            split = hit.split()
            card = Card(split[0], split[1])
            dealer.add_card(card)
        flag2 = True
        if (player.get_value() > dealer.get_value()):
            win += 1
            lossd += 1
        elif (player.get_value() < dealer.get_value()):
            loss += 1
            wind += 1
        elif (player.get_value() == dealer.get_value()):
            loss += 1
            wind += 1

# draw handler    
def draw(canvas):
    global flag1, flag2, deck, player, dealer
    # test to make sure that card.draw works, replace with your code below
    canvas.draw_text("Player's Hand:" + str(player.get_value()), (10, 350), 12, "Yellow")
    canvas.draw_text("Player", (40, 150), 12, "White")
    canvas.draw_text("Dealer", (40, 250), 12, "White")
    canvas.draw_text("Player Wins:" + str(win), (455, 350), 12, "White")
    canvas.draw_text("Player Losses:" + str(loss), (455, 380), 12, "White")
    canvas.draw_text("Dealer Wins:" + str(wind), (300, 350), 12, "White")
    canvas.draw_text("Dealer Losses:" + str(lossd), (300, 380), 12, "White")
    canvas.draw_text("BlackJack", (180, 40), 30, "Red")
    if (flag2 == False and player.get_value() <= 21):
        canvas.draw_text("Hit or Stand?", (180, 550), 20, "Black")
    for i in range(0, len(player.position)):
        player.draw(canvas, [player.position[i], player.position[0]], player.rank1[i], player.suit1[i])
    if (flag2 == True):
        dealer.draw(canvas, [dealer.position[0], dealer.position[1]], dealer.rank1[0], dealer.suit1[0])
    else:
        dealer.drawback(canvas, [dealer.position[0], dealer.position[1]])
    for j in range(1, len(dealer.position)):
        dealer.draw(canvas, [dealer.position[j], dealer.position[1]], dealer.rank1[j], dealer.suit1[j])
    if ((player.get_value() > 21) and (flag1 == True)):
        canvas.draw_text("Player is Busted", (180, 480), 20, "Black")
        canvas.draw_text("New Deal?", (180, 550), 20, "Black")
    elif ((player.get_value() == dealer.get_value()) and (dealer.get_value() >= 17) and (flag2 == True)):
        canvas.draw_text("Tie!! Dealer Wins", (180, 480), 20, "Black")
        canvas.draw_text("Dealer's Hand:" + str(dealer.get_value()), (10, 380), 12, "Yellow")
        canvas.draw_text("New Deal?", (180, 550), 20, "Black")
    elif ((dealer.get_value() > player.get_value()) and (dealer.get_value() >= 17) and (flag2 == True)):
        canvas.draw_text("Dealer Wins", (180, 480), 20, "Black")
        canvas.draw_text("Dealer's Hand:" + str(dealer.get_value()), (10, 380), 12, "Yellow")
        canvas.draw_text("New Deal?", (180, 550), 20, "Black")
    elif ((player.get_value() > dealer.get_value()) and (dealer.get_value() >= 17) and (flag2 == True)):
        canvas.draw_text("Player Wins", (180, 480), 20, "Black")
        canvas.draw_text("Dealer's Hand:" + str(dealer.get_value()), (10, 380), 12, "Yellow")
        canvas.draw_text("New Deal?", (180, 550), 20, "Black")

# deal an initial hand
player = Hand()
dealer = Hand()
deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()
for i in range(0, 2):
    deal1 = deck.deal_card()
    split1 = deal1.split()
    card1 = Card(split1[0], split1[1])
    player.add_card(card1)
    deal2 = deck.deal_card()
    split2 = deal2.split()
    card2 = Card(split2[0], split2[1])
    dealer.add_card(card2)

# initialization frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Blackjack", 600, 600)
frame.set_canvas_background("Green")

#create buttons
frame.add_button("Deal", deal, 200)
frame.add_button("Hit",  hit, 200)
frame.add_button("Stand", stand, 200)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)

# Start Program
frame.start()
```

If someone could help me work through this that would be awesome.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you intending `del self.deck` to do?  You haven't yet assigned any value to `self.deck`, so it's not there to delete, which is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: If you are trying to delete `self.deck` from the namespace so it doesn't overlap with the 'deck' in your main program, python is smart enough not to use the 'deck' in main if you make an assignment in your deck class. You should just be able to omit `del self.deck` and it will work fine. This is also an example where having overlapping variable names in different scopes can become confusing

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a `deal` object. It's attributes don't exist before its instantiated. The `del self.deck` is meaningless, unnecessary and the root cause; remove it.

```
# define deck class
class deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.choice = -1
        self.deck = []
```